# How do I call my methods to my main method?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I need to call my "sum" and "sumOfEvens" methods into the main method.  The "sum" method is for when the array contains the lucky numbers as seen in the "isLucky" method.  The "sumOfEvens" method adds of the even numbers if the array doesn't contain a lucky number.

So "sum" = true
and "sumOfEvens" = false

So here is my code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        luckyNumber1 = 7;
        luckyNumber2 = 13;
        luckyNumber3 = 18;


        int[] a=new int[10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers...");
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
            a[j] = sc.nextInt();



    }

    public static int sum(int [ ] value)  
    {
          int i, total = 0;
          for(i=0; i<10; i++)
          {
              total = total + value[ i ];
          }

          return (total);
    }
    static int sumOfEvens(int array[]) 
    {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++>) {
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
    }
    public static boolean isLucky (int[] array) 
    {

        if ( array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 13 || array[i] == 18 )
            return true; 

        else
            return false
    }

    // write the static methods isLucky, sum, and sumOfEvens

}
```

Comment: `int sum = sum(a);` and `int sumOfEvens = sumOfEvens(a);`?

Comment: @bohemian How do I apply it to the true and false?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean b = isLucky(a);

int result; 

if(b)
    result = sum(a);
else
    result = sumOfEvens(a);
```

Comment: Okay and does the letter b have any significance or can you just name it anything?

Comment: no .. i just declared a boolean variable .. if i am not wrong you want to call sum if the result of isluck is true

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
int result = isLucky(a) ? sum(a) : sumOfEvens(a);
```